# How to set Nexus container data disk space size?

Tags: docker, nexus3

Nexus v3.x running as a Docker container.

I setup a Ubuntu VM with 1TB disk space. However, the container seems to only use 180G (from `df -h` or `du -sh`), and has run out of space. Hence I can’t even log in. How can I set the amount of disk space the container uses?

I initially created the volume.

```
$ docker volume create --name nexus-data
```

I do this to start the container

```
$ docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --memory 16g --name nexus -v nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3
```

I essentially followed the steps at the bottom of [Sonatype Nexus3 Docker: sonatype/nexus3](https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3/). How can I let Nexus use, say 500GB of total disk space?

Answer (score 1):

Finally the docker log messages lead to a help (together with some googling). I was able to resolve it by this (but in my case I have just 8GB volume):

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8081 --name nexus -v nexus-etc:/nexus/etc -v nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3
docker ps
<... get id ...>
docker exec -it -u 0 [the id] bash
find -name "karaf"
<...>
cp ./nexus/etc/karaf/system.properties ./nexus/etc/karaf/system.properties.backup20220914
sed -i 's/diskFreeSpaceLimit=4096/diskFreeSpaceLimit=2048/g' ./nexus/etc/karaf/system.properties
```

Also check the filesystem type, there are some properties for docker volume limits.

Answer (score 0):

just pass the parameter -Dstorage.diskCache.diskFreeSpaceLimit=16384 to java